# Jupyter notebook is extremely slow when re-running cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a relatively large Jupyter/Notebook (about 40GB of Pandas DFs in RAM). I'm running a Python 3.6 kernel installed with Conda.

I have about 115 cells that I'm executing. If I restart the kernel and run the cells, my whole notebook runs in about 3 minutes. If I re-run a simple cell that's not doing much work (i.e. a function definition), it takes an extremely long time to execute (~15 minutes).

I cannot find any documentation online that has Jupyer notebook installation best practices. My disk usage is low, available RAM is high and CPU load is very low.

My swap space does seem to be maxed out, but I'm not sure what would be causing this.

Any recommendations on troubleshooting a poor-performing Jupyter notebook server? This seems to be related to re-running cells only.

Comment: Maybe your panda code needs optimization. [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the Variable Inspector nbextension is activated, it might slow down the notebook when you have large variables in memory (such as your Pandas dataframes).

See: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1275

If that's the case, try disabling it in `Edit -> nbextensions config`.

Comment: Wow i was wondering why it took me 2min to run a cell with `1+1` in it lol. Thanks for the pointer! Disabled this plugin everything is fine now

Comment: really effective

Comment: Wish I'd looked for this earlier. ++++