# VS code with Jupyter notebook is extremely slow when re-running cells

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I’ve got trouble with Jupyter in vscode. On vs code start-up, my 10 cells “run all” in about 3-4 minutes in a perfectly sensible way (loading the data and heavy calculations take time, but plotting is fast, etc). But re-running cells sometimes takes forever.

As an example, the last cell, which is just plotting the data, took 1.6s on 'run all'. When I instantly re-run that last cell (even without changing the code at all), it takes much longer to run (up to 14 minutes!). Why is that?

It isn’t a CPU or memory problem because those climb to only 30% and 75% during the runs, respectively.

I’ve seen [the same error on a Jupyter notebook server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025112/jupyter-notebook-is-extremely-slow-when-re-running-cells). The solution was to disable “Variable Inspector nbextension”. Is there an equivalent solution when running jupyter notebooks on vs code?

UPDATE: It's only the case when the "Jupyter: Variables" pane is open. A lot of variables are shown as loading endlessly. The problem might be that the variables are too big to show?

Versions: vs code 1.73.1 / Jupyter  v2022.9.1303220346 / Python 3.10.8 / Windows 11

Note: I have pandas variables, just like in the problem in the above link.

Comment: does that mean your re-run is fast when you don't have pandas variables? Can you create a dummy pandas DataFrame and a plot of that variable that takes a long rerun time? Do you have the same problem if you use the [Interactive Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) version

Comment: 1) No, I didn't mean re-run was fast without pandas. I just happens that the other link that's closely related to mine specifically mentioned that so I thought appropriate to mention it too.

Comment: 2) I did try with a small example but it runs and re-runs completely smoothly.

Comment: [ Note that I've updated my comment: The re-run (on my application, not the dummy example) is fast when the "Jupyter: Variables" pane is closed. When it's open, the re-run is very slow, and I noticed a lot of variables are shown as loading endlessly. This might be the source of the problem.  ]

Comment: 3) I'm not sure whether or not I'm currently using the Interactive Python version? I'm running cells manually (they look like cells and not like a regular text file). My code is in a ipynb file.

Comment: just try a `.py` file with `# %%` cell separators

Comment: what if you extend 2) to finally reach the original code and see which line adds the slow running

Comment: I face something similar even with cells that just contains some constant number. Don't know what's the reason, but I switched to jupyter lab and everything is great now.